# Ajax async : false freezes web page during loading in slow network

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous, synchronization

I use jquery AJAX for web page and use async : false option as following. My client's network is very slow. When I try to load the web page from the server web page is slow and all the controls are freeze. Is that "async:false" matter? here my code

```
function ajaxRequestWithNoArguments(url) {
    return $.ajax({
        url: urlForPhp + '/' + url,
        data: '',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        async: false,
        method: 'POST'
    });
}
```

Comment: I think it's in your url.. Why return ajax?

Comment: Of course, because you are using `async: false,`. This is expected behavior for one-threaded environment. Remove it and design your code properly without need for async: false.

Comment: Is it method: 'POST' or type: "POST"?

Comment: @Micaela it's both type and method, method was added in 1.9.

Answer (score 2):

> When I try to load the web page from the server web page is slow and all the controls are freeze. Is that "async:false" matter?

Yes, this is exactly why you should not use `async:false`, it's used in very specific cases and sounds like you don't need it. Making the request synchronous means that browser will pause program execution (freeze all UI too) until the request is done, the data is loaded back and processed. You don't wan't it in most cases, that's why you need to use default async: true.

```
function ajaxRequestWithNoArguments(url) {
    return $.ajax({
        url: urlForPhp + '/' + url,
        data: '',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        method: 'POST'
    });
}
```

Returning a promise object is convenient way to deal with asynchronous function. In this case you would use `ajaxRequestWithNoArguments` as follows:

```
ajaxRequestWithNoArguments('/some/url').then(function(response) {
    console.log('Data loaded', response);
});
```

Comment: Yes, but it's not the `then` which "fixes" the problem, it's making request asynchronous by removing `async: false`. Then you could use callback or promise pattern. Also take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call

Answer (score -1):

```
function OpenAjax(link, form_id)
        {
            document.getElementById("page-wrapper").innerHTML = "";
            $.ajaxSetup({ async: true });
            $("#page-wrapper").load(link, function(){
                $("#" + form_id).validator();
            });               
        }
```

This is my code. I had the same issue and setting it to true will fix it. When set it to true another problem may occur. Your javascript code will continue to work and  if you have a response text you must tell JQuery to run your code after response, as in my example:

```
$("#" + form_id).validator();
```

This code works after response, but if I write my code this way

```
  function OpenAjax(link, form_id)
            {
                document.getElementById("page-wrapper").innerHTML = "";
                $.ajaxSetup({ async: true });
                $("#page-wrapper").load(link, function(){
                 //Code moved from this line  
                }); 
                //Here
                $("#" + form_id).validator();              
                }
```

$("#" + form_id).validator(); - code will work before Ajax response